# What method will be used to define the color of the d3 charts whereas the color gets lighter when the value of the data is smaller?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, charts, visualization

This is the codes that are use to make my bar chart.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: black;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 200;
    height = 200;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Deaths:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.deaths + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.gender;}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.deaths; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "0")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("dx", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "right")
      .text("2008");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Deaths");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.gender); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand(1))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.deaths); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.deaths); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

    });

function type(d) {
  d.deaths = +d.deaths;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

[image: The bar chart that I have created]

The JSON file that I am using.

```
[{"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Female","deaths":"97"},{"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Male","deaths":"108"}]
```

What method in d3 should I use in my code so that the property of the color will be changed  to a lighter color when the value of the data is smaller? The below image is an example of what I am trying to implement into my chart. The color will be changed accordingly to the value of the data.

[image: The color of the graph]

Comment: Try to change the opacity value of rect based on rect-data, make some calculation to assign opacity value, or else make fiddle we will help you.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk I have edited my question above, please take a look and try to help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Answer for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: black;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Female","deaths":"97"},
            {"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Male","deaths":"108"}];
var deathArray = data.map(function(d){ return parseInt(d.deaths) });
var opacity = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([d3.min(deathArray), d3.max(deathArray)])
                .range([0.1,1.0]);

var margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 200;
    height = 200;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Deaths:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.deaths + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

 d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.gender;}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.deaths; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "0")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("dx", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "right")
      .text("2008");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Deaths");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.gender); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand(1))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.deaths); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.deaths); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
       .style("opacity",function(d){ return opacity(d.deaths) });

     }); 
    function type(d) {
  d.deaths = +d.deaths;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Try to understand the above code.
If you are not ask me.Okay

Comment: What I want is not the opacity. It is like the there are two y-axis. One of the value is let's say 10 and the other is 20. The value at the tip of 20 will be darker than the tip of the value 10. Whereas the higher the value is, the darker the chart will get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use d3 ordinal scales.

```
var deathArray = data.map(function(d){ return parseInt(d.deaths) });
var opacity = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([d3.min(deathArray), d3.max(deathArray)])
                .range([0.1,1.0]);
```

Apply opacity like this.

```
 svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")      
    .style("opacity",function(d){ return opacity(d.deaths) })
```

Comment: What I want is not the opacity. It is like the there are two y-axis. One of the value is let's say 10 and the other is 20. The value at the tip of 20 will be darker than the tip of the value 10. Whereas the higher the value is, the darker the chart will get.

Comment: You can try using d3.rgb(). Use brighter or darker method. Reference [d3 colors](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors)